# Why is it hashed differently when the same value is entered? In C

Tags: c, linux, hash, malloc, sha1

I am using SHA1 to encrypt my ID.

However, even if I enter the same ID, it is hashed differently.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *sha1_hash(char *input_url, char *hashed_url) {
    unsigned char hashed_160bits[20];
    char hashed_hex[41];
    int i;
    
    SHA1(input_url, 160, hashed_160bits);

    for(i=0; i < sizeof(hashed_160bits); i++) {
        sprintf(hashed_hex + i*2, "%02x", hashed_160bits[i]);
    }        

    strcpy(hashed_url, hashed_hex);

    return hashed_url;
}

int main()
{   
    char *input_url;
    char *hashed_url;
    
    while(1) {
        input_url = malloc(sizeof(char)* 1024);
        hashed_url = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
        
        printf("input url> ");
        scanf("%s", input_url);
        
                if (strcmp(input_url, "bye") == 0) {
                        free(hashed_url);
                        free(input_url);
                        break;
                }

        sha1_hash(input_url, hashed_url);
    
        printf("hashed_url: %s\n", hashed_url);
        free(hashed_url);
        free(input_url);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

If I enter the same value for the first attempt and the second attempt, it will be hashed differently, but the third attempt will be hashed the same as the second attempt.

I think the dynamic allocation is a problem, but I can not think of a way to fix it.

Comment: You never print the hashed ID, so how do you know it is "encrypted differently"? There are many other pieces missing too. Please post [mcve].

Comment: @EugeneSh. I made a mistake because the whole code was long and I'm sorry

Comment: @JohnFilleau I made a mistake the whole code was long.  I' sorry

Comment: @Yeon OK, you have provided the full code. Now please reduce it to a minimal one, which does not contain any unrelated stuff. In the process you might find that the code have started to function correctly - which will indicate that the "unrelated stuff" is causing the issues. Or you might find some other error. And, if neither, it will help us to focus on the specific problem.

Comment: @JohnFilleau  I didn't have the posture to ask questions. Sorry. I learned a lot from you. Thank you.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn't have the posture to ask questions. Sorry. I learned a lot from you. Thank you :)

Comment: Note well that hashing is not encryption.

Comment: Why, by the way, are you doing any dynamic allocation here in the first place?  You are allocating two buffers of fixed, modest length, that are not intended to live past the end of the the block in which they are allocated.  As such, you suffer all the complications of working with dynamic allocation, but gain nothing useful above what ordinary automatic allocation would give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `SHA1` correctly:

```
SHA1(input_ID, 160, hashed_ID_160bits);
```

The second parameter is the length of the data to hash.  You're instead passing in the number of bits in the hash.  As a result, you're reading past the end of the string contained in `input_ID` into uninitialized memory and possibly past the end of the allocated memory segment.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You instead want:

```
SHA1(input_ID, strlen(input_ID), hashed_ID_160bits);
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is not entirely correct. The fixed size '160' will never read past the allocated memory of 160 bytes, whereas it could happen if you use strlen and the string is in fact longer than 160 characters. To be entirely safe (and correct), it might be a good idea to obtain the length of the string and check, whether the buffer length is exceeded (which is a different problem entirely).

Answer (score 2):

```
SHA1(input_ID, 160, hashed_ID_160bits);
```

That line is wrong. You are always getting hash for 160 bytes. I assume you want the hash for the input text only, so use that length:

```
SHA1(input_ID, strlen(input_ID), hashed_ID_160bits);
```

---

SHA1 always produces hash of 160 bits, so you do not need to pass 160 as a parameter. If you want different size of SHA hash, you need to use a different function, [documented here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SHA1.html), and then of course modify rest of the code to match that hash size.

---

Why you get different hashes at different times is because of accessing uninitialized part of `malloc` buffer. This is Undefined Behavior, so "anything" can happen, and it's not generally useful to try and figure out what exactly happens, because it's not necessarily very deterministic. If you want to dig deeper than that, you could for example use a debugger to examine the memory addresses and contents on different loop iterations to see what exactly changed. Though, since this is Undefined Behavior, it's notoriously common for bad code to behave differently when you try to run it under debugger, or add debug prints.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the uninitialized memory you are allocating.

`malloc` reserves memory for you, but the contents are 'whatever has been in there before'. And since you are not only hashing the string contents, but the entire buffer, you get different results each time.

Try using `calloc`, running `memset` over the buffer or limit your hashing to `strlen(input)` and see if that helps.

Comment: Zeroing the buffer would probably lead to *reproducible* hashes, but it is not an appropriate solution if the OP wants to generate hashes that match those that other people compute independently for the same inputs.  Only the data actually input should be hashed, in which case zeroing the other bytes of the buffer is irrelevant.

Comment: Additionally, if input is longer than 160 characters, it's not hashed completely. Strings which differ only after first 160 characters would always just produce the same (wrong) hash.

Comment: The question was, why the OP gets different hashes each time, which I answered. Zeroing the buffer will fix their immediate problem. Furthermore, I have also offered using 'strlen' to determine the length of the input to obtain better hashes. If the buffer size is exceeded by the input, a different problem will arise first.